# Geometrical significance

Tags: calculus, substitution

What is the geometric significance of substitution? For instance substituting 
$x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ in the following problem to find the limit.
$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\tan(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$. Of course, this manipulation/substitution makes it easier to solve, but geometrically what does the above substitution mean. 
I hope the question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the geometrical interpretation as follows:

As the definition of limit requires the convergence for **any** sequence, the change to polar coordinates parametrizes in an easy way all **linear** (in the sense, along a line) approaches to the point, the angle parametrizes the slope at which we approach the point.

Comment: Thank you. Further sir, we make substitutions everywhere in calculus - integrations (usually indefinite integrals), differentiation etc. What is   the geometric interpretation in these cases.

Comment: my geometric interpretation in these cases, is to parametrize the space with circular level lines of different radii instead of horizontal and vertical